# How to combine a character in a Python link

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a question how to properly link to get: `/home/.../GUI/module/*`. I need to have the result as string so that it corresponds: `r'/home/.../GUI/module/*'`?

I am currently receiving something like this: `//home/adrian/Pulpit/Projekty_Korbowo/GUI/module*`

Code:

```
directory = ''
directory = filedialog.askdirectory() #-> link of dir: /home/.../GUI/module 
file_dir = directory.join('/*')
```

Comment: I don't understand. Does `askdirectory` actually return those `...`? The result of that should already be a usable string.

Comment: Also, you are using `join` wrong (probably, depending on what you want to do). The correct use is `separator.join(parts)`, so you join the characters `/` and `*` using your original path as separator, getting that `//...*` path.